# c++ websocket server, how not create thread. and convert idle loop system

Tags: c++, websocket

example websocket :

```
std::thread{ wsserver }.detach();

void()
{
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket{ ioc };
        acceptor.accept(socket);
}
```

The thread process is running separately from the server.
I think this may lead to erroneous results in some interlinked operations.
so I want to put this process into an infinite loop.
In short, I should not use multi-threads.

I want.
example:

```
while(loop());

int loop()
{
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket{ ioc };
  acceptor.accept(socket);

  return 1;
}
```

but not work idle loop.
because "acceptor.accept" is all time waiting connect.

How to use a different command instead of the "accept" command.
How I can also get rid of your thread command.
Can I do this with smart data?

I hope I can explained.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you still take the multithreading approach but read up on std::mutex to prevent threading issues with shared state. For a beginner, it is far easier to get something off the ground than if you were to rewrite the thing using an event loop.

Comment: @Botje
Yes, I'm new to this.
you are right but
A lot of processing will be done through this loop.
so I didn't want to use threads.
because I need to use mutex for every conflicting value of program and thread.
Also, does mutex only work between threads?
Or does it work between the program and the thread as well?

example:
The program is constantly adding +1 to the value of x with the while loop.
if we interfere with this value with the thread.
Is it possible to fail +1 worth of downtime and thread tampering?
Does mutex make the 2 of them work synchronously?

Comment: That is *way* too broad a question for stackoverflow, let alone a comment. I suggest you do some research, pick a strategy, and start working on it.